# Keras fit() versus train_on_batch() loss difference

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I plan to train a NN with multiple arrays, and I understand this isn't possible with `fit()`. So I've tried to recreate what `fit()` does (at least in part, for now) using `train_on_batch()`. After training a very simple Keras sequential model, I've observed a large difference in loss when comparing `fit()` and my own `train_on_batch()` loop. This is with `epochs` and `batch_size` equal to 1, which I think is the simplest test case.

In the following example, `ab` is an ndarray containing float32 amplitude data from a previous run of an `rfft()`. `labels` is an ndarray containing integers, either 0 or 1 for binary classification.

```
ab = np.load(absName)
ab2 = np.transpose(ab)
labels = np.load(labelName)

l = ab.shape[1]
fftSize = ab.shape[0]

assert l == len(labels)

print("ab.shape     =", ab.shape)
print("ab2.shape    =", ab2.shape)
print("labels.shape =", labels.shape)
print("l =", l)
print("fftSize =", fftSize)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, input_shape=(fftSize,)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.compile(
        optimizer="rmsprop",
        loss="binary_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"])

epochs = 1
batchSize = 1
useFit = True

if useFit:
    model.fit(ab2, labels, batch_size=batchSize, epochs=epochs, verbose=0)
else:
    for i in range(0, epochs):
        j = 0

        while (j + batchSize) < l:
            model.train_on_batch(ab2[j:j+batchSize], labels[j:j+batchSize])
            j += batchSize

        if j < l:
            model.train_on_batch(ab2[j:l], labels[j:l])

score = model.evaluate(ab2, labels, verbose=1)

for i in range(0, len(score)):
    print("score[" + model.metrics_names[i] + "] = " + str(score[i]))
```

Output from the prints in all cases:

```
ab.shape     = (513, 168)
ab2.shape    = (168, 513)
labels.shape = (168,)
l = 168
fftSize = 513
```

If `useFit` is True, the score printed is:

```
score[loss] = 0.36022053304172696
score[acc] = 0.8809523809523809
```

If `useFit` is False, the score printed is:

```
score[loss] = 0.49978475148479146
score[acc] = 0.8809523809523809
```

This is a large difference in loss. If I try 10 epochs and a batch size of 32, they both produce a loss of ~35. I'm not sure this is a reliable experiment though, as I understand that shuffling occurs between epochs.

**I was under the impression that my custom training loop does exactly what `fit()` does (ignoring shuffling as `epochs=1`), but I must be missing something. Any ideas?**

Comment: For a single epoch, the loss difference isn't too large, and is within model's variance; have you tried running `train_on_batch` several times with identical settings (without 'seeds')? Also, `fit`'s `shuffle` defaults to `=True` - while `train_on_batch` has no `shuffle`; if your pasted code is exact, this is a major factor.